# React Slick with rows

Tags: reactjs, slick.js

I want to add the slick carousel in my react app.
This is the origin code:

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

I found the react-slick, but in the base code, it possible add multiple rows (responsive)

In the react-slick component this possible does not work
https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/502

How can I use the slick gallery in react with all the options that exists in the origin code.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the following to your settings variable:

```
rows: 2
slidesPerRow: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

in your responsive settings add row=2

responsive : [{
breakpoint : 600,
settings : {
slidesToShow : 3,
slidesToScroll : 2,
rows : 2,
}
}]

Answer (score -1):

```
I have implemented slick carousel in my react app. Please find below code : 

class SimpleSlider extends React.Component {
 render() {
      var settings = {
      dots: true,
      autoplay: true,
      arrows: true
    };

    return (
      <Slider {...settings}>
          <div><img src='../../src/assets/1.jpg' /></div>
          <div><img src='../../src/assets/2.jpg' /></div>
          <div><img src='../../src/assets/3.jpg' /></div>
          <div><img src='../../src/assets/4.jpg' /></div>
        </Slider>
    );
}
}

If you want to add rows dynamically you can add that as well, you will need to make single row as a template in JavaScript and append it inside <Slider> component dynamically. Hope this would be helpful to you.
```

Answer (score -1):

slick oly updating the current row not every which is been view
for eg. multiple rows 2 showing den still have to move two slides at a time but only updating 2 slides not 4